# Missing return statement error in Parser class

Tags: java, split, return

so I have a Parser class that reads in user input and splits it at every "/". This si my second time making a class like this,  but this time I have to parse the string two different ways based on what the value of split[0] is aka the first value. Im not sure what to put in for the return type because all the class is doing is taking the string that is entered, splitting at every "/". and then assigning those inputs to variables in other classes. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Here is the class

public class DrinkParser {

```
public static Drink parseStringToDrink(String lineToParse){ //ERROR: missing return statement.

    String regex = "[/]";
    String [] split = lineToParse.split(regex);


    if ("Box".equals(split[0]) || "box".equals(split[0])){

       DrinkInBox dIB = new DrinkInBox(split[1], Double.parseDouble(split[2]), Integer.parseInt(split[3]), Integer.parseInt(split[4]), Integer.parseInt(split[5]));
       return dIB;

    }

    if("Cylinder".equals(split[0]) || "cylinder".equals(split[0])){

        DrinkInCylinder dIC = new DrinkInCylinder(split[1], Double.parseDouble(split[2]), Integer.parseInt(split[3]), Integer.parseInt(split[4]));
        return dIC;
    }

}
```

}

Last time I wrote a class like this, all I had to do was read in the string regardless of what split[0] is...heres that class just in case.

public class BankParser{

```
public static Bank bankParser(String lineToParse){ //parses the string and sets the bankName,bankID, and bankAddress based off the inputed String

    String regex = "[/,]"; 
    String[] split = lineToParse.split(regex);
    Bank b = new Bank();
    b.setBankName(split[0]); //sets the first split to the BankName
    b.setBankID(split[1]); // sets the second split to the BankID
    b.setBankAddress(split[2], split[3]); //set the city to the third split and the state to the fourth split in BankAddress
    return b;

}
```

}

Comment: Do you need a return or can you just put a void return type and just set the values?

Comment: @AlexJohnson The method `parseStringToDrink` appears to be a `static` factory method, so it should return the appropriate `Drink` object.

Comment: return null after the second "if" statement and let the caller class make the decision on what to do when the parser returns null.

Answer (score 0):

What if `split[0]` is neither `"Cylinder"` nor `"Box"`?  There is no `return` statement for that case.  It's probably an error in that case, so throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad drink type: " + split[0]);
} // end of parseStringToDrink
```